# How to remove or gray-out a category in Wordpress's post editor?

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is there a way to remove a category from the post editor category meta box in wordpress?

Reason being, I have a category structure like this:

> blog (parent category)
>
> category1 (child category)
>
> category 2 (child catgeory)

That "blog" parent category is there just to handle URL structure. If we select a child category (category1 in the following example), the post will have the url structure of:

> .../blog/category1/(title)

I want my writers to ONLY select the child categories though, because if "blog" is selected in addition to another category, it will default the URL to:

> .../blog/(title)

So I'm looking for a way to remove "blog" from the post editor meta box and only allow the selection of its child categories (and all categories are children of "blog" for my purposes). Can you remove a category from that meta box, or can you gray it out so that its unselectable?

If what I'm doing seems weird, I'm open to tips on handling url structure on WP too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trick is a little bit rude, but I think it works.
You can hide the category with css' display:none
Go to your theme's function.php and add these lines

```
<?php function hide_cat(){ ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        li#category-x{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
<?php } add_action( "admin_head", "hide_cat" ); ?>
```

Where x is the number of the category (find it in the html code when edit a random post)

Hope this works :)

Comment: Use `add_action( "admin_head-post.php", "hide_cat" );` and `add_action( "admin_head-post-new.php", "hide_cat" );` to print only in those screens. Right now your `admin_head` is printing everywhere and this may have unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info brasofilo. I'll add that in.

Answer (score -2):

I usually just hide the class in css

```
.entry-mata {display:none}
```

Or what ever you may need to hide.